# UIBarButtonItem image/glyph in Standard UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I'm trying to create a 'Refresh' button containing the standard UIBarButton refresh system glyph, which, when tapped, will animate a custom view, then fire another selector to call the intended refresh action.

I know I could do this with images and two inner views added to a custom view, but is there any way to do it with the standard glyphs from UIBarButtonItem? Are they available at all for UIButtons?

Answer (score 0):

When I was creating my iOS application, I wasn't able to find a "refresh" button for the UIBarButtonItem.  I had to take a Rounded Rect Button and place it in the top right hand corner and create a custom image to overlay onto it.

Edit: You can find it in IB. When you add the UIBarButtonItem, select it and then select the attributes inspector tab.  Click the Identifier drop down and within that there is a selection to change the button to look like the system refresh button.

Comment: I did mention that I can already do it with a UIImageView, I wanted to use the refresh system glyph.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.  Are you trying to put this in an area other than on the Navigation Bar? If so... I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: It's supposed to go in the navigation bar. I just wanted the refresh image to disappear when the button was tapped, to be replaced by an activity spinner. When my data has finished loading, I want to hide the spinner and show the image again.